# Setup a DNS wilcard and MX record in the same zone

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, wildcard

I'd like to know how to configure my DNS to be able to use a wildcard for my domain and an MX record together. Here is what I've done:

```
@   IN SOA dns98.ovh.net. tech.ovh.net. (2012052100 86400 3600 3600000 300)
              IN  NS     ns98.ovh.net. 
              IN  NS     dns98.ovh.net. 
              IN  MX 1   mail.gestixi.com. 
              IN  A      91.125.39.211 
*             IN  CNAME  mydomain.com. 
www           IN  CNAME  mydomain.com.
```

The problem is that when I check my DNS, I get this error:

```
MX records shall not point to an alias defined by a CNAME
```

Because of this error, it look like I can't send mails from some internet providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mail.gestixi.com` needs to be an `A` record, instead of getting caught by the wildcard `CNAME`.

If it's on that same server, then just give it an `A` record:

```
mail          IN  A      91.121.39.211
```

I'm not sure how strictly relays actually enforce this part of the standard, since it just causes some extra lookups, but it's better to be on the compliant side!

Comment: Perfect! My problem is solved and I can now send mail !!! Thanks a lot. Just a last question, can you tell me if I can remove my www CNAME record since I'm already using a wildcard ?

Comment: @NicolasBADIA Yes, you can safely remove that record.